# Left joint dataset with partial string matching [R]

Tags: r, string, dplyr, left-join

I would like to ask how to perform left joint operation with 2 datasets when variable to joint by has different string.

I know it can be done "by-hand" but I would prefer more efficient approach

I provided 2 datasets in [HERE](https://1drv.ms/u/s!Aha5nHo4JhEaq3ZtfoghLr7CsMbb?e=OBQhdf).

Here are some rows from each data set.

**all_data**

```
   GID_0 NAME_0   GID_1               NAME_1 NL_NAME_1      GID_2    provstate    VARNAME_2 NL_NAME_2      TYPE_2  ENGTYPE_2 CC_2
1    FRA France FRA.1_1 Auvergne-Rhône-Alpes      <NA>  FRA.1.1_1          Ain         <NA>      <NA> Département Department   01
2    FRA France FRA.1_1 Auvergne-Rhône-Alpes      <NA>  FRA.1.2_1       Allier Basses-Alpes      <NA> Département Department   03
3    FRA France FRA.1_1 Auvergne-Rhône-Alpes      <NA>  FRA.1.3_1      Ardèche         <NA>      <NA> Département Department   07
4    FRA France FRA.1_1 Auvergne-Rhône-Alpes      <NA>  FRA.1.4_1       Cantal         <NA>      <NA> Département Department   15
5    FRA France FRA.1_1 Auvergne-Rhône-Alpes      <NA>  FRA.1.5_1        Drôme         <NA>      <NA> Département Department   26
6    FRA France FRA.1_1 Auvergne-Rhône-Alpes      <NA>  FRA.1.6_1  Haute-Loire         <NA>      <NA> Département Department   43
7    FRA France FRA.1_1 Auvergne-Rhône-Alpes      <NA>  FRA.1.7_1 Haute-Savoie         <NA>      <NA> Département Department   74
8    FRA France FRA.1_1 Auvergne-Rhône-Alpes      <NA>  FRA.1.8_1        Isère         <NA>      <NA> Département Department   38
9    FRA France FRA.1_1 Auvergne-Rhône-Alpes      <NA>  FRA.1.9_1        Loire         <NA>      <NA> Département Department   42
10   FRA France FRA.1_1 Auvergne-Rhône-Alpes      <NA> FRA.1.10_1  Puy-de-Dôme         <NA>      <NA> Département Department   63
```

**data_to_insert**

```
   provstate               count
   <chr>                   <int>
 1 Alpes-Maritimes            13
 2 Alsace                     13
 3 Aquitaine                 119
 4 Aude                        1
 5 Auvergne                    1
 6 Auvergne-Rhone-Alpes       10
 7 Bas-Rhin                    5
 8 Bouches-du-Rhone            9
 9 Bourgogne-Franche-Comte     6
10 Brittany                   23
```

I need to connect datasets that dataframe called ***all_data*** will contain new variable called **count** that is found in ***data_to_insert*** dataframe - joint should be based on *provstate* variable. (provstatet that do not have values in ***data_to_insert*** dataframe should have value 0 in new left joined dataframe)

However names are slightly different in both dataset.

I would like to ask for any advice

Comment: maybe [fuzzyjoin](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/fuzzyjoin/fuzzyjoin.pdf) can  be of some help? Also: A [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610#5963610) would make it way easier to help you than having to download extra files... ;)

Comment: I see many city names in France from both data sets. Some cities exist in both data sets. Some others do not. Can you explain what you expect with clear examples?

Answer (score 2):

As far as I inspected, it seems to me that you want to change some letters such as `è`, `ô` and `é`. In `all_data` you have these letters in the city names. But you do not have city names with these letters in `data_to_insert` (e.g., Côtes-d'Armor vs. Cotes-d'Armor). Hence, I decided to replace these letters having accents with normal alphabets. This will help your join process to some extent. (Or this is may be enough for you.)

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringi)

mutate(all_data, provstate = stri_trans_general(provstate, "latin-ascii")) -> all_data

left_join(all_data, data_to_insert, by = "provstate")
```